# swift uiview does not have a member named center

Tags: ios, uiview, swift

This is my `RectangleView`:

```
import UIKit

class RectangleView: UIView
{
    init(frame: CGRect)
    {
        // Initialization code
        super.init(frame: frame)
    }

    /*
    override func drawRect(rect: CGRect)
    {
        // Drawing code
    }
    */
}
```

I add this `RectangleView` on my `CustomViewController`:

```
import UIKit

class CustomViewController: UIViewController
{
    var ballX:Int = 0
    var ballY:Int = 0
    let BALLWIDTH:Int = 50
    let BALLHEIGHT:Int = 50
    var navigationHeight:Double = 0.0
    var pos:CGPoint?
    var rectangleView:RectangleView?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

        self.ballX = Int(arc4random_uniform(320));
        self.ballY = Int(arc4random_uniform(480));
        self.navigationHeight = Double(self.navigationController.navigationBar.frame.size.height)
        var rect = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.BALLWIDTH, height: self.BALLHEIGHT)
        self.pos = CGPoint(x: self.ballX, y: self.ballY);

        println("x: \(self.ballX), y: \(self.ballY)")

        self.rectangleView = RectangleView(frame: rect)
        self.rectangleView!.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()

        self.view.addSubview(self.rectangleView!)

        NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(0.05, target: self, selector: Selector("moveBall"), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    }

    func moveBall()
    {
        self.rectangleView!.center = CGPointMake(self.rectangleView!.center + self.pos!.x, self.rectangleView!.center + self.pos!.y)
    }
...
```

And I get a error message

```
'RectangleView?' does not have a member named 'center'
```

Should I define this `center` on my `RectangleView`? My `RectangleView` inherits from `UIView`, so I feel very confused. Thanks your help.

---

**Edit**

I use this code

```
func moveBall()
{
    if let rv = self.rectangleView {
        rv.center = CGPointMake(rv.center + self.pos!.x, rv.center + self.pos!.y)
    }
```

I get the new error message

```
'CGPoint' is not convertible to 'UInt8'
```

I think the `rv.center` type is `UInt8`, but `self.post!.x` is `nsnumber`, so I how could I convert to `CGPointMake` accept type? I have convert `UInt8(self.pos!.x)` and convert calculate result to `CGPointMake` accept type again?

Have any other best method? Thanks your help.

Comment: I'm curious. What happens if you add a second ! when you try to access center. `self.rectangleView!!.center` ?

Comment: The same, that give me the same error message.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The values returned by `!`-unwrapping an optional are currently immutable (see [Lattner's explanation](https://github.com/ksm/SwiftInFlux#mutable-optional-value-types)).

Try:

```
if let rv = self.rectangleView {
  rv.center = ...
}
```

I think this can be considered a known bug in Swift.

Comment: Hi, I got a new problem, I have edit my question, thanks your help

Comment: You're adding an int to a point. Instead of `rv.center + self.pos!.x` you need `rv.center.x + self.pos!.x`. Same goes for the y coordinate.

Comment: Oh my god, I forget it! Thanks your help.